# Why is this C preprocessor code not Working?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#define GC_APP_NAME_LIT myapp
#define GC_APP_DOMAIN_LIT mydomain
#define GC_NATIVE_FUNCTION_DEF(name,args) GC_NATIVE_FUNCTION_DEF_FINAL(GC_APP_DOMAIN_LIT,GC_APP_NAME_LIT,name,args)
#define GC_NATIVE_FUNCTION_DEF_FINAL(domain,game,name,args) Java_com_##domain_##game_Game_##name args

void GC_NATIVE_FUNCTION_DEF(nativeFunc, (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)) {
    ...
}
```

Using the above code, I am assuming that a function with the following signature will be created.

```
void Java_com_mydomain_myapp_Game_nativeFunc(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)) {
    ...
}
```

But this does not appear to be working.

On the other hand, A simpler version of this setup works perfectly.

```
#define GC_NATIVE_FUNCTION_DEF(name,args) Java_com_mydomain_myapp_Game_##name args

void GC_NATIVE_FUNCTION_DEF(nativeFunc, (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)) {
    ...
}
```

. . . and creates the function signature as desired.

Need help with identifying what am I doing wrong here. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

test.h

```
#define GC_APP_NAME_LIT myapp
#define GC_APP_DOMAIN_LIT mydomain
#define CONCAT(a,b,c,d,e,f) a ## b ## c ## d ## e ## f
#define GC_NATIVE_FUNCTION_DEF(name,args) GC_NATIVE_FUNCTION_DEF_FINAL(GC_APP_DOMAIN_LIT,GC_APP_NAME_LIT,name,args)
#define GC_NATIVE_FUNCTION_DEF_FINAL(domain,game,name,args) CONCAT(Java_com_, domain, _, game, _Game_, name) args

void GC_NATIVE_FUNCTION_DEF(nativeFunc, (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)) {
...
}
```

Let's pass it through the preprocessor.. `gcc -E test.h`:

```
# 1 "test.h"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.h"

void Java_com_mydomain_myapp_Game_nativeFunc (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {
...
}
```

Comment: interesting reading to explain this behavior : [argument prescan](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `#define`s  are processed in order.  Try moving `GC_NATIVE_FUNCTION_DEF_FINAL` *before* `GC_NATIVE_FUNCTION_DEF`.

Comment: Still No good. I believe there is something fundamentally wrong with using ## within the macro like I have done.